# Can i 3d rotate an image on the Y axis 10-15 degrees from php?

Tags: php, rotation, gd, jpeg

From [image] I want to create [image]

Is this possible with php?

Comment: Ugh. It's surely possible but there's no ready-made function for it. Can you use ImageMagick?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [PHP GD Image Perspective](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503646/php-gd-image-perspective)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set Perspective of an Image Using PHP GD:

http://www.jqueryit.com/2010/03/set-perspective-of-image-using-php-gd.html

If you have Imagemagick:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-distortimage.php

Comment: Thank you all for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

You can, with imagemagick. [Here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#perspective) is the ImageMagick documentation for that kind of processing.

Answer (score 1):

You could "fake" the effect by putting a white mask with transparent center corresponding to the desired rotation over the image.

Comment: It won't actually fake that effect, since parts of the image will be cut off. Edit: still I take back my -1, since it might be a semi-acceptable solution sometimes.

Comment: I didn't say it would achieve the exact result, I said you could fake it... It would look like a photo rotated in 3d space, but the perspective would be incorrect. I'm just proposing a quick hack.