# Apply perspective on pattern image using PHP(preferable) or Python

Tags: php, python, imagemagick, php-gd

Trying to achieve image perspective with full ratios(height-width) of original image.

[PHP GD image perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503646/php-gd-image-perspective)
This above link is the closest solution to our problem, but the height-width ratio of visible pattern getting changed from original image, as there are transparent area left somewhere.

What we really need is to fill the transparent portion of final image with same perspective of pattern.[image]

Comment: You need to get the fill pattern from somewhere and assume your example is just an example not an actual image you will be using? I would join two images together side by side, change the perspective and then crop from the centre.

Comment: Thanks @Bonzo for your reply, but what i really need is to covert the whole image itself with original height width after applying perspective. Please follow this [link](http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/6062/Hh1YrN.jpg)

Comment: And where are you going to get the fill in texture from? You may not have understood my suggestion. With my suggestion you put two copies of the original together side by side. Distort the image and then crop it back to the original size. The corners will then be filled with the same texture as you started with an image twice as wide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables instead of fixed dimensions but I will let you sort that out

```
convert "input.jpg" "input.jpg" +append -matte -virtual-pixel transparent -distort Perspective "0,0 400,-200   1146,0 746,-200   1146,412 1146,412   0,412 0,412 " -gravity south -crop 573x412+0+0 +repage "output.jpg"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again @Bonzo. I did try a quite similar solution earlier, but there was a problem in that, when you crop a portion from center the perspective is not as clear or you may say impact is more accurate at the top in given example instead at the center of final image, so cropping from center is not accurate and is not the thing what i am looking for. Also we dont want to change in original pattern size i.e.  if pattern ratio is 50*50 ,after applying perspective ration will not increase , it will have decrease the ration like 45*45
Still thanks for your precious reply

Comment: http://storage1.static.itmages.com/i/16/0521/h_1463828654_2019066_798c632ecc.jpeg